# Poll() with POLLOUT event always returns 0 when two threads are polling, but works with one

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, driver, linux-device-driver

I am using a program called Netmap. I have two interfaces (eth0 and eth1) and I create a netmap instance on each of the interfaces.

Let's call the file descriptor of eth0's netmap instance as **fd0**. Eth1's will be **fd1**. Also, the event here is **POLLOUT**.

If I have one thread polling either interface, then `poll()` always returns positive. As soon as I create a 2nd thread to poll the other interface, then both of the `poll()` calls return 0.

Example: I create a thread to `poll()` on fd0. `poll()` always returns a positive value. As soon as I `poll()` on fd1, both `poll()`'s return 0.

Why is this?

Comment: If this still actual, you can compile netmap with verbose output and read dmesg log. What error poll returns? Another case is netmap can't poll host ring concurently? but I am not sure here. Additionaly you can read netmap_poll(() function in netmap.c. Maybe you will find something interesting for you.